# Wrong address model when compiling boost

Tags: python, boost, mingw, boost-python

I have written a program that mixes Python 3 and C++. I am using boost-python 1.62 and mingw on Windows. I have compiled the C++ python libs on many, many machines so far and it has always worked well. Now I gave the sources to a colleague for installation on his machine, and compilation fails with mingw complaining about problems with symbols and 'file format not recognized'.

What I see, though, is the following: On my machine b2 reports this at the start of compile:

- 32-bit                   : no  (cached)
- 64-bit                   : yes (cached)
- arm                      : no  (cached)
- mips1                    : no  (cached)
- power                    : no  (cached)
- sparc                    : no  (cached)
- x86                      : yes (cached)
- symlinks supported       : yes

On my colleague's machine it looks like this:

- 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
- arm                      : no  (cached)
- mips1                    : no  (cached)
- power                    : no  (cached)
- sparc                    : no  (cached)
- x86                      : yes (cached)
- symlinks supported       : yes

I am quite sure that the problems have to do with his system trying to compile 32-bit code and trying to link existing 64-bit code to it. The question is, though, why is it trying to compile 32 bit code in the first place? The machine is less than a year old, so it is definitely 64 bits. The more important question, however, is, how can I persuade the machine to compile with 64 bits?

By the way, this is my user-config.jam:

```
using python : 3.6 : C:\\StreamTest\\WinPython-64bit-3.6.6.2\\python-3.6.6.amd64\\python.exe
  : C:\\StreamTest\\WinPython-64bit-3.6.6.2\\python-3.6.6.amd64\\include
  : C:\\StreamTest\\WinPython-64bit-3.6.6.2\\python-3.6.6.amd64\\libs
  : ;
```

Comment: Your colleague should install *MinGW-W64* (http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php). Is this the case?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, my colleague is runing exactly the same software as I.

Answer (score 2):

Your colleague is definitely compiling to 32-bit, you could add the argument `-m64` which should force `mingw` to compile to 64-bit (assuming your colleague has a version which supports cross compatibility i.e. mingw-w64)

I assume your colleague downloaded http://www.mingw.org/ but he/she needs: http://mingw-w64.org

**From mingw.org:**

> "MinGW is a native Windows port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC),
> with freely distributable import libraries and header files for
> building native Windows applications; includes extensions to the MSVC
> runtime to support C99 functionality. Although (currently) offering
> only a 32-bit compiler suite, all of MinGW's software will execute on
> the 64bit Windows platforms."

**From mingw-w64.org:**

> "Mingw-w64 is an advancement of the original mingw.org project,
> created to support the GCC compiler on Windows systems. It has forked
> it in 2007 in order to provide support for 64 bits and new APIs. It
> has since then gained widespread use and distribution. "

Comment: I just let him run b2 -m64. That does not change anything. But when I do b2 -m32 on my machine, it still compiles to 64 bits. Anything else I need to tell b2 to make it honor that flag?

Comment: can you try with either or both of these flags: architecture=ia64 or address-model=64 -> I'm on Linux at the moment so it's a bit hard to check.

Comment: It's still saying 32 bits: yes

This is what gcc -v prints out:

gcc -v
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/StreamDesigner/WinPython-64bit-3.6.6.2/python-3.6.6.amd64/share/mingwpy/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
[...]
Thread model: win32
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

Comment: I'm now thinking the problem has to do with b2 rather than gcc. Do the -m32 and the other flags you suggested get passed to gcc by b2? I am still not clear on what b2 actually does. I find boost python to be overwhelmingly complex.

Comment: I will get back to you in the evening after testing on a windows machine, sorry for slow replies.